# I am trying to sum candidate votes by summing up votes for all counties in a state for a candidate

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

Here is my code. It only returns 0 for all keys. I want to know why my loop is not summing votes for the same state and candidate.

```
with open(IN_PATH, 'r') as in_file:
    dict_reader = csv.DictReader(in_file)
    
    tuple_dict = {(i["year"], i["state_po"], i["county_name"], i["candidate"]): int(i["candidatevotes"]) 
    if i["candidatevotes"] != "NA" else i["candidatevotes"] == "" for i in dict_reader if i["year"] == "2020"} 

    count_dict = {(k[0], k[1], k[3]):0 for k in tuple_dict.keys()}

    for k,v in tuple_dict.items():
        if k[1] and k[3] in count_dict:
            count_dict[k[1]] += v
        else:
            count_dict[k[1]] = v
```

Here is a sample of my output:

```
{('2020', 'AL', 'JOSEPH R BIDEN JR'): 0, ('2020', 'AL', 'OTHER'): 0, ('2020', 'AL', 'DONALD J TRUMP'): 0, ('2020', 'AK', 'JOSEPH R BIDEN JR'): 0, ('2020', 'AK', 'OTHER'): 0, ('2020', 'AK', 'JO JORGENSEN'): 0, ('2020', 'AK', 'DONALD J TRUMP'): 0, ('2020', 'AZ', 'JOSEPH R BIDEN JR'): 0, ('2020', 'AZ', 'OTHER'): 0, ('2020', 'AZ', 'JO JORGENSEN'): 0, ('2020', 'AZ', 'DONALD J TRUMP'): 0, ('2020', 'AR', 'JOSEPH R BIDEN JR'): 0, ('2020', 'AR', 'OTHER'): 0, ('2020', 'AR', 'JO JORGENSEN'): 0, ('2020', 'AR', 'DONALD J TRUMP'): 0, ('2020', 'CA', 'JOSEPH R BIDEN JR'): 0, ('2020', 'CA', 'OTHER'): 0, ('2020', 'CA', 'JO JORGENSEN'): 0, ('2020', 'CA', 'DONALD J TRUMP'): 0, ('2020', 'CO', 'JOSEPH R BIDEN JR'): 0, ('2020', 'CO', 'OTHER'): 0, ('2020', 'CO', 'JO JORGENSEN'): 0, ('2020', 'CO', 'DONALD J TRUMP'): 0, ('2020', 'CT', 'JOSEPH R BIDEN JR'): 0, ('2020', 'CT', 'OTHER'): 0, ('2020', 'CT', 'JO JORGENSEN'): 0, ('2020', 'CT', 'DONALD J TR
```

Here is a sample of my data:

```
"year","state","state_po","county_name","county_fips","office","candidate","party","candidatevotes","totalvotes","version","mode"
2000,"ALABAMA","AL","AUTAUGA","1001","PRESIDENT","AL GORE","DEMOCRAT",4942,17208,20191203,"TOTAL"
2000,"ALABAMA","AL","AUTAUGA","1001","PRESIDENT","GEORGE W. BUSH","REPUBLICAN",11993,17208,20191203,"TOTAL"
2000,"ALABAMA","AL","AUTAUGA","1001","PRESIDENT","RALPH NADER","GREEN",160,17208,20191203,"TOTAL"
2000,"ALABAMA","AL","AUTAUGA","1001","PRESIDENT","OTHER","OTHER",113,17208,20191203,"TOTAL"
2000,"ALABAMA","AL","BALDWIN","1003","PRESIDENT","AL GORE","DEMOCRAT",13997,56480,20191203,"TOTAL"
```

Comment: Your `tuple_dict` definition is puzzling. You have `int(i["candidatevotes"]) if i["candidatevotes"] != "NA" else i["candidatevotes"] == 0`. This is either `int(i["candidatevotes"])`, which is an int, or `i["candidatevotes"] == 0`, which is False. Is that what you intended?

Comment: can you add some example output that you want to the question?

Comment: @khelwood yes, because the candidate votes column in the raw data was made up of strings and had missing values stated as 'NA'

Comment: @RohitPatil {('2020', 'AL', 'JOSEPH R BIDEN JR'): 849624, ......}

Comment: Why would you want `i["candidatevotes"] == 0` in a context where you just established that `i["candidatevotes"]` is equal to `"NA"`? Obviously if it is "NA" then it is not 0.

Answer (score 1):

```py
    for k,v in tuple_dict.items():
        if k[1] and k[3] in count_dict:
            count_dict[k[1]] += v
        else:
            count_dict[k[1]] = v
```

you are assigning a tuple as the key when you are creating the count_dict, and then trying to access the dictionary using a single value as a key. this is creating a new key and then storing values there instead of adding it to the key you intended to add it to.

this is what you actually need to do, as far as i understand.

```py
    for k, v in tuple_dict.items():
        if k[1] in count_dict and k[3] in count_dict: # check k[1] and k[3] are in the count dict
            count_dict[(k[0], k[1], k[3])] += v
        else:
            count_dict[(k[0], k[1], k[3])] = v
```